# Skip characters in file when using collections.generic.ienumerable(of string)

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I am using the Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of String) function to get the first and last lines of a file.

This works, but what I want to do, is skip past any lines that contain the # character.

My code:

```
Dim Lines As Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of String) = File.ReadLines(strFileName)
Line0 = Lines.FirstOrDefault
LineN = Lines.LastOrDefault
lowestFreq = Line0.Split(New Char() {","c})
highestFreq = LineN.Split(New Char() {","c})
lowFreq = lowestFreq(0)
highFreq = highestFreq(0)
```

I have tried variations of if / if not etc. but I just can't seem to find a solution.

My file looks like this (some files have more comment lines than others)

```
# a comment
# the date
#
# some other stuff
12.599,3.513
15.874,4.246
20.000,4.884
25.198,5.912
31.748,6.063
40.000,7.020
50.397,6.267
63.496,7.251
80.000,6.875
etc..
```

.

The # will only ever occur at the top of the file.

Comment: You can use a Linq where clause to exclude the # lines...

Comment: `File.ReadLines(sFile).Where(Function(q) q.StartsWith("#") = False)`

Comment: Plutonix is on the right track.  Use that `Where` clause in your declaration of the `lines` variable.  Then when you call `FirstOrDefault` and `LastOrDefault` against `lines` they will both be filtered.  There are also overloads of `FirstOrDefault` and `LastOrDefault` that take predicate arguments, so you don't actually need `Where`.

Comment: Thank you, and thanks to Plutonix - it works well!

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
Line0 = Lines.FirstOrDefault
```

to this:

```
Line0 = Lines.SkipWhile(Function(s) s.StartsWith("#")).FirstOrDefault()
```

That said, by doing that, you are going to enumerate those lines of the file twice.  Given that you want the last line and must thus read the whole file anyway, you should probably call `ReadAllLines` instead of `ReadLines`.